# What's the hook for filtering every texts of site?

Tags: plugin-development, hooks

I'm developing a plugin to replace a character that google doesn't show it with an accepted character. I want to get all the texts that wordpress returns (content, comments, title, names, etc.) but I don't know what hook should I use to do it. Can anybody help me?

Comment: [Try the Codex Filter Reference](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference). This question is far too broad for WPSE's question-and-answer format.

Comment: In addition to what @Chip said: also see Adam Brown's [WordPress Hooks Database](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's [a lot](http://adambrown.info/p/wp_hooks/hook/filters) of filter hooks available, and your question is rather board. However, generally WordPress-generated content is handled by three hooks:

- [`the_title`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title): applied to the post title retrieved from the database, prior to printing on the screen (also used in some other operations, such as trackbacks).
- [`the_content`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content) : applied to the post content retrieved from the database, prior to printing on the screen (also used in some other operations, such as trackbacks).
- `comment_text`: applied to the comment text before displaying on the screen by the comment_text function, and in the admin menus

These filters only moderfy the front-end of your site, meaning that the content will appear unfiltered in the admin area and in the database.

You can filter the content attatched to these hooks by writing a PHP function and then registering it with your hook:

```
add_filter( 'comment_text', 'my_func' );
```

To see an example of how these filters can be used, have a look at the [`capital_P_dangit()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/capital_P_dangit) function.